# How to combine multiple rows into a single row in pandas dataframe grouping using a subset of the row string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I would like to transform the format of this pandas dataframe from

```
  individual_id  Rec  Sig
0    C11 part 1  0.2  0.8
1    C11 part 2  0.1  0.9
2    C12 part 1  0.3  0.7
3    C12 part 2  0.5  0.5
4    C13 part 1  0.1  0.9
5    C13 part 2  0.7  0.3
```

to this format

```
  individual_id  Rec 1  Rec 2  Sig 1  Sig 2
0           C11    0.2    0.1    0.8    0.9
1           C12    0.3    0.5    0.7    0.5
2           C13    0.1    0.7    0.9    0.3
```

Where `Rec 1` and `Rec 2`now represent the parts of `individual_id` but in a single row. However, for some `individual_id` there may be 3 parts. I hope this makes sense. I tried using df.groupby but it seems more difficult to do with multiple parts of the row names. Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: In the original dataframe, first element of `individual_id` is `C11 part 1`? Another question, when `Individual_id` is 3 parts, what do you expect to be in `Rec 1`, `Rec 2` ,...?

Comment: kindly add those that are more than 2 parts

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful if you add the data with more than two parts.

For your current case, You can extract the required values from `individual_id` before reshaping with `pivot`:

```
reshape = df.assign(
    num=df.individual_id.str[-1], individual_id=df.individual_id.str[:3]
).pivot("individual_id", "num")

# it could also be " ".join(x)
reshape.columns = reshape.columns.map("_".join)
reshape.reset_index()


    individual_id   Rec_1   Rec_2   Sig_1   Sig_2
0           C11     0.2     0.1     0.8     0.9
1           C12     0.3     0.5     0.7     0.5
2           C13     0.1     0.7     0.9     0.3
```